# Unable to get Boxplot displayed in Apache Superset

Tags: visualization, apache-superset

I'm using Apache Superset0.35 for visualisation.While trying to implement boxplot chart,it displays only horizontal line instead of boxplot & all the values are same [Min,Max,Median..]. Is it necessary to have time-series column in the data file?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the metric of the column data to be displayed was not configured. The time series column has no problem

Comment: Are you the same person as Levanya K.R. in the question? How do you know what their problem was, almost a year later, with no information or code provide din the question?